# Null string retrieve in prepared/bound parameter query SQLite on C

Tags: c, sqlite

Iam trying to step a simple SELECT query using C and SQLite3, I make it before, but for any strange reason now isn't working the database is very simple:

```
CREATE TABLE service(
id integer primary key autoincrement,
name text,
url text);
```

the C code is that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <sqlite3.h>

int error(char *message, sqlite3 *db) {
  fprintf(stderr, "[ %s ] Error: %s\n", message, sqlite3_errmsg(db));
  return SQLITE_ERROR;
}

void usage(char *appname) {
  printf("Usage: %s <service-name>\n", appname);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

  if (argc < 2) {
    usage(argv[0]);
  }

  sqlite3_stmt *stmt = NULL;
  sqlite3 *db = NULL;
  int rc;

  const char *service_name = NULL;

  int idx = -1;

  char *sql = "select * from service where name is :name";
  int sql_len = strlen(sql);

  sqlite3_initialize();

  rc = sqlite3_open_v2("getip.db", &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL);
  if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
    error("Connecting to database", db);

  rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, sql_len, &stmt, NULL);
  if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
    error("Preparing statement", db);

  char *service_search = argv[1];
  idx = sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(stmt, ":name");
  rc = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, idx, service_search, strlen(service_search),
      SQLITE_STATIC);

  rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
  service_name = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2);

  printf("[debug] Last code: %d\n", rc);
  printf("[debug] SQL: %s\n", sqlite3_sql(stmt));

  printf("Name: %s\n", service_name);

  sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

that must be returned the value of column 'url' but return null, and another little doubt is that, the documentation from SQLite3.org mention a function for getting SQL from a statement 'expanded' (char 
*sqlite3_expanded_sql(sqlite3_stmt *pStmt);), but at compile i obtain:

undefined reference to `sqlite3_expanded_sql'

the last doubt is not important, the really headache is the first one.

Comment: You need to make sure that `sqlite3_step()` returns `SQLITE_ROW` before trying to use any of the `sqlite3_column_XXX()` functions...

Comment: I have add some verification code: ```rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
 if (rc == SQLITE_ROW)                                                                                        
   service_name = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2);
 else
   error("Stepping statement.", db);```  and get the error: [ Stepping statement. ] Error: no more rows available, any idea whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Ok, Im sorry for a very dumb question, but the fact is the problem was with de test data argument pass to the program, but really thanks to Shawn, with the verification code that i add and comment before, i can see my very silly mistake.